# Как правильнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Без всяких" или "безо всяких" - как правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотелось бы увидеть в контексте. В целом, возможны оба варианта, но не всегда.

Answer (score 2):

Интересно, когда это нельзя сказать "без всяких причин" или "безо всяких причин"? Чем это может быть ограничено? Я думаю, что контекст и не нужен. Оба варианта правильны. 
Добавление гласного **о** к предлогу **без** наблюдается в сочетаниях с местоимениями весь, всякий, например: безо всего, безо всяких колебаний (наряду с «без всяких колебаний»). (Розенталь. И у Ожегова то же. И в других словарях)

Comment: Похоже, тут кочующая ошибка.
Безо всего - это не от "весь", а от "всё". Да и то чаще - в значении "без одежды", "без вещей" и в просторечном стиле.
От "весь" - "без всего (груза, багажа, пафоса, отпуска и т.д.)". "Безо" тут как-то даже не выговариается.

Answer (score 1):

Это орфоэпические варианты. Оба возможны, но второй - более разговорный.