# Чередование "без - безо"

Tags: орфография, фонетика

Наткнулась на предложение: "Его осудили без(о) всякой вины".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как здесь правильнее сказать: "безо всякой" или все-таки "без всякой"? "Без" как-то литературнее, но зато "безо" фонетически лучше звучит (иначе выходит слишком много согласных подряд).
А как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без - безо

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?rub=ko_dnu

Предлог безо употребляется перед формами родительного падежа слов весь, всякий наряду с предлогом без: без всяких сомнений и безо всяких сомнений; без всех сотрудников и безо всех сотрудников.

Повтор [Как правильнее?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5)

Вариант БЕЗО, скорее всего, исключает стечение согласных, неудобных для произношения:  зубные З и С и губно-зубный В.