# "БЕЗ львов" или "БЕЗО львов"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

*Сафари **безо** львов — не сафари. // Сафари **без** львов — не сафари.*
Какой из вариантов правильный?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **Сафари без львов – не сафари.**

Пояснение  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/69-ko-dnu

**Без ― безо**

Предлог ***безо*** употребляется перед формами родительного падежа слов ***весь, всякий*** наряду с предлогом ***без***: без всяких сомнений и безо всяких сомнений; без всех сотрудников и безо всех сотрудников.

Также: [Чередование "без - безо"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45795/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE)

Comment: Так и было, но Word исправляет на "безо". А здесь - "с" или "со"? Большая пустующая территория с множеством офисов, никого из сотрудников нет, в том числе и сторожа.

Comment: Виктор, оформите это как отдельный вопрос.